# Install triggers for google scrips projects from google drive api

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-api

I have a number of python scripts that copy and create spreadsheet files on my google drive using the google drive api. Some of these files have projects of google scripts that make use of installable triggers. When a file is copied the corresponding project is also copied and added to the new file, but the triggers are not.

Is there a way to use the google api for python to copy or create the triggers that the project uses? As it is, any copy will have broken functions due to the lack of installable triggers.

Comment: Nope. You can only create triggers from Apps Script code or from Apps Script related GUIs (ie. from the editor or the developer hub).

Comment: Publish and use a private add on to avoid having hundreds of copies of the same Apps Script code that need to get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved by using the **Google API** but there a couple of alternatives available.

#### Method 1 - Manage triggers programmatically

You can create and choose the settings you want for the triggers through Apps Script.

For example the following trigger will run on the function you choose every number of hours you want:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionOnWhichTheTriggerWillRunOn')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(NoOfHours)
      .create();
```

#### Method 2 - Publish a private add-on

If all the users you have are in a private domain, you can create and publish a private add-on since this would be much easier and time-efficient. Moreover, iff you are a G Suite domain administrator, you can **install** published add-ons for your domain users.

Furthermore, I suggest you check the following links since they might be of help in your future development:

- [ScriptApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app);
- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Add-ons Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).